# How to map long and narrow objects

Tags: uv

so Im trying to map a sword, but my problem its that the uvmap is barely used because the weapon is long, so it is all compressed in the same side. What could be a better way to do that?

[image]

Comment: Does the image need to be square?

Comment: Yeah, it has since is for a videogame

Comment: Can more than one object share the UV

Comment: The problem remains since is a very long object. Should I cut it in hald of the blade? Would it be bad? (Because seems)

Comment: but videogames do not need to have square textures per se. you should check if you could get away with a 4096 x 521 map. other techniques could be to stretch your unwrap or make the blades texture tile from top to bottom, this could be a problem if you want to bake a normal map, though

Comment: @morph3us There is a video or something where I could take an example? In blender I think there is no way to change the UV, or at least I never saw how

Comment: If you really can't use a long texture you could split the long islands up in segments to they could arranged better. It will be harder to create the textures if you don't use a 3d painter.